# How to add Azure service call to appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on adding an Azure Cognitive Search service to my .NET Core app, and don't want to mess anything up. The tutorial says to add the following to my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "SearchServiceName": "<placeholder-Azure-Search-service-name>",
  "SearchServiceAdminApiKey": "<placeholder-admin-key-for-Azure-Search>",
  "AzureSqlConnectionString": "<placeholder-ADO.NET-connection-string",
}
```

Problem is, my appsettings.json file already has stuff in it:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=XChange;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

When I try to add the Azure API call at the bottom it says only one top-level item is allowed, and if I assign some key to it inside the top-level json object I'm afraid the API won't work -- I don't use JSON very much and I'm new to .NET so sorry if this is a stupid question, I couldn't find any docs explaining what to do

Answer (score 0):

It means your JSON is incorrect , you need to have it in the form of object with a key. Do something like

```
 {
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=XChange;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Configuration": {
    "SearchServiceName": "<placeholder-Azure-Search-service-name>",
    "SearchServiceAdminApiKey": "<placeholder-admin-key-for-Azure-Search>",
    "AzureSqlConnectionString": "<placeholder-ADO.NET-connection-string"
  }
}
```